# Angular 6 - What my doing wrong to get Data from observable?

Tags: arrays, typescript, get, observable, angular6

first of all, I followed this example: [Heroes](https://stackblitz.com/angular/ooqemvjyqkb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fheroes%2Fheroes.component.ts) as reference. The only difference
is the API method, that in my case is post instead of get;

I have this Interface:

```
export interface IContasMae {
codEstab: string;
codProduto: string;
desContaMae: string;
codRep: number;
numQuantidade: number;
numValVenda: number;
numValMedio: number;}
```

In service I have the method:

```
  getContasMae() : Observable<IContasMae[]> {
    if (this.getUser()) {   
      return this.http.post<IContasMae[]>(`${environment.api_url}/getContasMae`,''); 
    }
  }
```

the property contasMae definition on component is:

```
export class PanelDashboardComponent implements OnInit {
  public contasMae: IContasMae[];
```

(IContasMae is the interface above)

On component, the method is called like this:

```
this.service.getContasMae().subscribe(contasMae => 
  {
    console.log('Observable:',contasMae);
    this.contasMae = contasMae;
  });
console.log('Resultado:',this.contasMae);
}
```

The console.log of Observable shows:

```
Observable: {contasMae: Array(10)}
contasMae: Array(10)
0: {codEstab: "001", codProduto: "PRODUCT 1", desContaMae: "Account 1", codRep: "0", numQuantidade: "70302.8", …}
1: {codEstab: "001", codProduto: "PRODUCT 1", desContaMae: "Account 2", codRep: "0", numQuantidade: "391937.15", …}
2: {codEstab: "001", codProduto: "PRODUCT 1", desContaMae: "Account 3", codRep: "0", numQuantidade: "1638", …}
3: {codEstab: "001", codProduto: "PRODUCT 1", desContaMae: "Account 4", codRep: "0", numQuantidade: "3795", …}
4: {codEstab: "001", codProduto: "PRODUCT 2", desContaMae: "Account 5", codRep: "0", numQuantidade: "320000", …}
5: {codEstab: "001", codProduto: "PRODUCT 2", desContaMae: "Account 6", codRep: "0", numQuantidade: "2140", …}
6: {codEstab: "001", codProduto: "PRODUCT 2", desContaMae: "Account 7", codRep: "0", numQuantidade: "660", …}
7: {codEstab: "001", codProduto: "PRODUCT 2", desContaMae: "Account 8", codRep: "0", numQuantidade: "128616", …}
8: {codEstab: "001", codProduto: "PRODUCT 2", desContaMae: "Account 9", codRep: "0", numQuantidade: "128540", …}
9: {codEstab: "001", codProduto: "PRODUCT 2", desContaMae: "Account 10", codRep: "0", numQuantidade: "2056", …}
length: 10
__proto__: Array(0)
__proto__: Object
```

But, the console.log of this.contasMae shows:

```
Resultado: undefined
```

What is wrong? How can I get the result in this.contasMae?

Someone could help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding how Observables work. If you tell me what you're trying to do with the value of `this.contasMae` I can give you a nice detailed answer.

Comment: thanks so much your help Dan. I need to take the data to use in template (ngFor for example), and also I need to summarize the products and revenue total, take the keys for graphs labels and values. I need to handle the array (forEach, Sort, etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you're trying to do with `this.contasMae`.

I assume, since this is in a component you're trying to display this in a template. If that's the case you can simply have:

```
<div>{{ contasMae | async }}</div>
```

`async` is an Angular pipe that handles asynchronous data in your views.

To iterate over the list in your view:

```
<li *ngFor="let item of contasMae | async" [value]="item">{{item}}</li>
```

Remember that Observables are asynchronous so in your example, what's happening is that your `console.log()` is executing before the Observable has resolved an emitted value.

You can see some examples of the `async` pipe here: https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe

If you're planning on using the value of `this.contasMae` inside of your component class then one way to do that is to wrap any logic using the instance variable inside of a method on your component class.

For example:

```
public ngOnInit() {
    this.service.getContasMae().subscribe(contasMae => 
    {
        console.log('Observable:',contasMae);
        this.contasMae = contasMae;
        doSomething();
    });
}

public doSomething() {
    console.log('Resultado:',this.contasMae);
}
```

In the above case, you know that `this.contasMae` will not be accessed until after a value emitted from your observable has resolved and assigned the result to `this.contasMae`.

Comment: Wow! amazing! - do I have to assign this.contasMae inside doSomething? How (and when) can I take permanently this.contasMae data? Please, be patient, i'm just a beginer.

Comment: No worries :) This is assuming that `contasMae` is a public instance member of the class. So it would be defined above your constructor. Since the data is asynchronous you can never use it without handling that fact.

Comment: Dude, you are Da Man! You save my life. Thank you very, very much.

Comment: @HeberPaesFomin No problem dude :) If that's the answer you were looking for do you mind making it the accepted answer? Thanks!

Comment: Hey, ladies and gentleman. I can see that you benefited from the answer, but you didn't give it an up-vote. Please do so. I did.

Comment: @WilliamHou Appreciate it!